# find the field names from a search query

Tags: python, arrays, string, pandas, dataframe

i have a where condition query.and i want to make a dataframe with those fields  inside the where condition.
Question is how to extract those fields from inside the where condition.

I tried things like finding the string before any operator(like ==,>=,&,/) using rstrip,lstrip.But still not successful. i do beleive some string search method will do it but i am not getting it.
 my where condition is

```
whereFields == "CITY_NAME == 'city1' & EVENT_GENRE == 'KIDS' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1$#$FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME == 'city1' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FANTASY' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1$#$CITY_NAME == 'city1' & EVENT_GENRE == 'FESTIVAL' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1$#$CITY_NAME == 'city1' & EVENT_GENRE == 'WORKSHOP' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1$#$CITY_NAME == 'city1' & EVENT_GENRE == 'EXHIBITION' & count_EVENT_GENRE >= 1$#$CITY_NAME == 'city1' & FAV_GENRE == '|DRAMA|'$#$CITY_NAME == 'city1' &  & FAV_GENRE == '|ACTION|ADVENTURE|SCI-FI"
```

i want the field names involved.like my dataframe should have all unique columns.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re    
res = [re.split(r'[(==)(>=)]', x)[0].strip() for x in re.split('[&($#$)]', whereFields)]
```

seems to work. Now you may want the unique ones, and no empty field:

```
res = [x for x in list(set(res)) if x]
```

Comment: but it read the duplicates for every field name except the first field name city_name..How is that possible.  if it is written for getting unique or non duplicate fields.then it should be applicable to all fields not the first one only.  BTW great help.   But i can delete duplicate later but if  a single line will do i will be very happy.

Comment: Oh, you have strange `$#$` instead of `&` at some places. I edited the code.

Comment: Apart from that I don't understand what you meant in your comment. The second line with `list(set())` gets rid of duplicates.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but i want the unique values in single code line of yours  res = [re.split(r'[(==)(>=)]', x)[0].strip() for x in re.split('[&($#$)]', whereFields)]     If this code can get the fields  then why not unique ones. Then there will not need of writing extra code line to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: can u please help me with creating a dataframe with field names from that list output value .And Thanks u saved my 1 hr time today.

Comment: I don't know about pandas, but I would use `splits = [re.split(r'[(==)(>=)]', x) for x in re.split('[&($#$)]', whereFields)]` and build a dictionary based on these elements (keys at index 0, values at index 2).

Comment: To have it in one line, use `list(set([re.split(r'[(==)(>=)]', x)[0].strip() for x in re.split('[&($#$)]', whereFields) if x]))`

Comment: Thanks again.can u help me in this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686399/find-all-matched-dataframe-pairs

Comment: then `[x for x in list(set([re.split(r'[(==)(>=)]', x)[0].strip() for x in re.split('[&($#$)]', whereFields)])) if x]`. Try to understand it (splitting into several lines actually helps understanding). It is just including one expression into the other.

Comment: @ muraveill.i am new to this whole pythonic stuff.So my ignorance to these kind of complex line is obvious.and i am trying to learn faster.

Comment: Sure, I just meant it was a good exercise to try and split it up into smaller parts - many lines - instead of the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [98]:
pd.DataFrame(data = pd.Series(re.findall('\w+ *(?==|<|>)' , whereFields)).unique() , columns = ['fields'])
Out[98]:
    fields
0   CITY_NAME
1   EVENT_GENRE
2   count_EVENT_GENRE
3   FAV_VENUE_CITY_NAME
4   FAV_GENRE
```

Comment: Almost. `count_EVENT_GENRE` is missing.

Comment: Thanks Nader,but i wanted to do that using reg function actually,you just taught me an extra way and a numpy function  Thanks.

Comment: thanks @muraveill for your comment , I've updated my answer