# Find all matched dataframe pairs

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe having several fields and two of them are `CUST_NAME` and `DATE_OF_PURCHASE`.

I have to find each customers tenure. For that I want to find each customers first transaction and then find the days between then and today. Then I have to find avg days between their transactions.

I currently sort the date field by ascending, find the unique customer names. Then search the total dataframe by unique customer name.

However I'm only getting one customer's data. Can anyone explain why I'm only getting one result?

Here's a sample of the data:

```
     CUSTOMER_MAILID    TRX_DATE
0     0007ayan@gmail.com  21/04/2013
1     0007ayan@gmail.com  12/05/2013
2   000.tushar@gmail.com  18/05/2013
3     0007ayan@gmail.com  03/06/2013
4     0007ayan@gmail.com  15/06/2013
5     0007ayan@gmail.com  30/06/2013
6     0007ayan@gmail.com  10/07/2013
7     0007ayan@gmail.com  23/07/2013
8   000.tushar@gmail.com  07/12/2013
9     0007ayan@gmail.com  19/12/2013
10      00078r@gmail.com  22/01/2014
11      00078r@gmail.com  16/02/2014
12      00078r@gmail.com  01/03/2014
13      00078r@gmail.com  01/03/2014
14      00078r@gmail.com  01/03/2014
15      00078r@gmail.com  07/03/2014
16      00078r@gmail.com  08/03/2014
17      00078r@gmail.com  06/04/2014
18      00078r@gmail.com  11/04/2014
```

And here's my code:

```
df.sort(['TRX_DATE'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
df_unique_cust = df['CUSTOMER_MAILID'].unique()
for df_unique_cust in df['CUSTOMER_MAILID']:
      df_pair = df[df.CUSTOMER_MAILID == df_unique_cust]
```

Comment: Could you attach your code attempts and piece of your dataframe?

Comment: i have attached, please ,do give an code example.

Comment: You are overwriting the variable `df_unique_cust` with the loop variable, so the statement with `unique()` will be useless.